# Creating new Portfolio object through SSJS but the status shows error

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, automationstudio

I am trying to create a portfolio object in the scrip activity using SSJS portfolio add function.I am following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_portfolioAdd.htm) link for creating portfolio but the status shows error.

```
var newPortfolio = {
DisplayName : "SSJS Portfolio Object",
CustomerKey : "myPortfolioCK",
CategoryID: 12345,
FileName : "logo.png",
FileLocation : "http://www.example.com/Portals/0/images/global/logo_main.png"
};

var status = Portfolio.Add(newPortfolio);
```

I have just used the sample image URL from google in the file location.What i am missing here?My actual requirement is to download image from the image URL which i am getting from API response.

Comment: Did you change the CategoryID to the correct ID instead of 12345 in your final call? Also assuming by your question that you changed the file location to an actual image instead of the example listed.

Comment: Yes ,I have changed the file location and actual file location.I just tried with some test images from google images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1")` to the code, it works perfectly.

See below example:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1")

var newPortfolio = {
DisplayName : "Your_DisplayName",       //Replace with your Displayed Name
CustomerKey : "Your_ExtKey",      //Replace with the external key of picture
CategoryID: 8675309,           // Replace with your folder ID
FileName : "Your_Filename.png",   //Replace with the filename of your picture
FileLocation : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/01/21/toolbox-155603_960_720.png" 
                            //Replace with URL of your picture
};

var status = Portfolio.Add(newPortfolio);

Write(status);
</script>
```

I ran this from a LP in my account and it worked correctly returning a status of OK.

Comment: Hi changing the Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1") did the trick.

Comment: Hi Gortonington can you also check this question  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206617/url-concatenation-is-not-working-in-the-content-area-generated-by-ssjs